# null pointer exceptions in android code?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps, android-intent

> 2:10:25.524: E/AndroidRuntime(2019): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 01-06
>   12:10:25.524: E/AndroidRuntime(2019): Process: com.kandy, PID: 2019
>   01-06 12:10:25.524: E/AndroidRuntime(2019):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.kandy/com.kandy.citymap}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 01-06 12:10:25.524:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(2019):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
>   01-06 12:10:25.524: E/AndroidRuntime(2019):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
>   01-06 12:10:25.524: E/AndroidRuntime(2019):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 01-06
>   12:10:25.524: E/AndroidRuntime(2019):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
>   01-06 12:10:25.524: E/AndroidRuntime(2019):   at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 01-06
>   12:10:25.524: E/AndroidRuntime(2019):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 01-06 12:10:25.524:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(2019):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 01-06
>   12:10:25.524: E/AndroidRuntime(2019):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 01-06
>   12:10:25.524: E/AndroidRuntime(2019):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 01-06 12:10:25.524:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(2019):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>   01-06 12:10:25.524: E/AndroidRuntime(2019):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 01-06
>   12:10:25.524: E/AndroidRuntime(2019):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 01-06 12:10:25.524:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(2019): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   01-06 12:10:25.524: E/AndroidRuntime(2019):   at
>   com.kandy.citymap.onCreate(citymap.java:25) 01-06 12:10:25.524:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(2019):   at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 01-06
>   12:10:25.524: E/AndroidRuntime(2019):     at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
>   01-06 12:10:25.524: E/AndroidRuntime(2019):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)

I am using google maps for this one

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class citymap extends Activity {
    GoogleMap gmap;


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.citymap);



        gmap=((MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        gmap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);//line 25


        gmap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);


        gmap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(7.2964, 80.6350),12));
        gmap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(7.2964, 80.6350)).title("Kandy"));
}}
```

Comment: I am gonna assume gmap.setMapType() is what is causing your NPE? It would be because your map isn't inflated yet so getMap returns null. Just a guess.

Comment: Mark your line number 25.

Comment: start by formating your stacktrace so it is actually readable

Comment: @BeingMIAkashs marked it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok do the next your getting null onCreate method when your trying to find view of gmap(your doing right) and after which your trying straight away to get a map with function `get map()`(here your doing wrong) just do the next

```
gmap=((MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));
 gmap.getMap();
```

never use a method (getMap(),or something familiar) when your finding the View of your thing!

Answer (score 0):

Use SupportMapFragment instead of MapFragment. Try the following code snippet

```
SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

gmap = fm.getMap();
```